# Problemas de StaleElementReferenceException em Selenium com Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

sou novo aqui no fórum,espero que possam me ajudar, estou criando uma aplicação com selenium utilizando python para coletar documentos em um site específico. os documentos são carregados para download via javascript e então meu loop só pega o primeiro documento e ao tentar pegar o segundo dá erro StaleElementReferenceException, segue abaixo uma amostra do html e o bloco de código que estou usando.
Obs.: Estou usando python 3.6 e driver do chrome. Eu quero pegar apenas os links da segunda coluna da tabela.

```
    <table id="GRDDOCS" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="780" class="Texto" style="z-index:100;width:780;height:20;">
  <tbody><tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="90" class="texto1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="300" class="texto1">
      <a href="#" onclick="return SubmitClickConfirm('GRDDOCS','6_1', true, '')"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LINK11; return false" id="LINK11" name="LINK11" style="z-index:100;font-weight:bold;font-size:9px;text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;">documento.jpg</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="170" class="texto1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LINK12; return false" id="LINK12" name="LINK12" style="z-index:100;">Excluir</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="170" class="texto1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="90" class="texto2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="300" class="texto2">
      <a href="#" onclick="return SubmitClickConfirm('GRDDOCS','7_1', true, '')"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LINK13; return false" id="LINK13" name="LINK13" style="z-index:100;font-weight:bold;font-size:9px;text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;">documento02.jpg</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="170" class="texto2">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LINK14; return false" id="LINK14" name="LINK14" style="z-index:100;">Excluir</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="170" class="texto2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="90" class="texto1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left" nowrap="" width="300" class="texto1">
      <a href="#" onclick="return SubmitClickConfirm('GRDDOCS','8_1', true, '')"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LINK15; return false" id="LINK15" name="LINK15" style="z-index:100;font-weight:bold;font-size:9px;text-decoration:none;color:#FF0000;">documento03.jpg</a>
    </td>
```

Bloco de código:

```
    if driver.find_element_by_id("GRDDOCS"):
   table_id = driver.find_element_by_id("GRDDOCS")
   rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
   for row in rows:
     col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  
       if col.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a"):
         prop = driver.find_element_by_link_text(col.text)
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", prop)
         time.sleep(5)
```

Bom dia galera, fiz as seguintes alterações, adicionei uma espera explicita após pegar o primeiro documento para verificar se os elementos retornam para a página e faço print caso encontre e tento pegar o documento de novo mas sem sucesso, alguem pode me ajudar? segue código atualizado abaixo:

```py
if driver.find_element_by_id("GRDDOCS"):
  table_id = driver.find_element_by_id("GRDDOCS")
  rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
  for row in rows:
      col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]
      if col.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a"):
          prop = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(col.text)
          self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", prop)
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120).until(
                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "GRDDOCS"))
               )
          time.sleep(5)
          if element.is_displayed:
              self.logger.info(f"Elemento visível: 
               {element.is_displayed()}")
              self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro só ocorre em duas situações:

1. **Quando o elemento a que você está fazendo referência é removido da página, através de javascript ou outro método.**

   Essa é a situação mais comum. Alguma coisa ocorre na página, decorrente de execução de código dinâmico em javascript ou de interação do usuário, e o elemento não está mais lá. A parte onde ele está pode ter sido recarregada, ou o usuário pode ter navegado para outra página. O elemento pode também ter sido substituído, via código javascript, por outro elemento com o mesmo ID ou atributos.
2. **Quando o elemento não está mais à árvore DOM.**

   Certas páginas dinâmicas usam métodos para simular abas em uma aplicação web. Uma das formas de fazer isso é criar `div`s para cada aba, mas só anexar uma das `div`s ao DOM e armazenar o restante em variáveis. Neste caso, pode acontecer de o seu script ter referência a um objeto que não está mais anexado à árvore DOM (isto é, não é mais filho de `document.document`).

Em ambos os casos não existe uma forma de reanexar o objeto e trabalhar com ele. Você tem que descartar o objeto e buscá-lo novamente no DOM, através de uma das funções do Selenium de localização de elementos (`find_elements` por exemplo).