# Problema ao navegar com Selenium (usando Python) em resultados de uma busca apresentados em HTML dinâmico

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scraping

Estou realizando um scraping de matérias de um jornal pernambucano (Diário de PE) conforme uma busca que fiz com algumas palavras-chave sobre o assunto de interesse. A busca do jornal retorna 10 resultados em uma página com HTML dinamico, contendo, ao final, uma lista com todas as paginas de resultados, numeradas de 1 a 10.

Quanto à 1ª pagina, eu consegui fazer o scraping do trecho que desejo do HTML utilizando o Selenium em Python sem grandes problemas, mas estou tendo problemas para acessar as demais páginas a partir da lista gerada.

As referências para as próximas páginas estão em tags `<div class="gsc-cursor-page" aria-label="Página 2" role="link" tabindex="0">2</div>`(tomando como exemplo a referência para a 2ª pg.). Não há uma tag âncora `<a>` associada a um href gerando o hiperlink para a próxima pagina e nem um botão "próxima". Vide um exemplo disso na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha estratégia: criei uma função que pegar as referências das páginas nessas divs dando os caminhos através do XPATH. Essas referências foram armazenadas em uma lista, e criei um laço 'for' para iterar referencia após referência, utilizando a função click() do Selenium para acessá-las. Criei essa estratégia baseado em várias dicas dadas no próprio Stackoverflow (versão em inglês) e infelizmente ela não funcionou, e só a 2ª página é retornada (além da 1ª).

Abaixo estão os código das duas funções que criei, a primeira para pegar o HTML da 1ª página, e a segunda para fazer isso nas demais, usando a lista que comentei.

**Bibliotecas importadas:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
```

**Primeira função para fazer o scraping do HTML da área desejada na página inicial de resultados da busca:**

```
def get_target_html(url):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)
    #Finding target HTML
    site_html = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-expansionArea"]').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    driver.close() 
    with open('target_page_1.html', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(site_html)
```

**Segunda função para navegar para as demais páginas e fazer o scraping do HTML:**

```
def get_next_pages(url): 
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    #Creating a list that receives all elements according to the given XPATH
    page_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page"]')
    #Reading each element in the list to access the related page and get the target HTML code
    count = 1
    for page in page_list:
        count += 1
        number = str(count)
        page.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        target_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-expansionArea"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        #Writing and saving a html file with the target code
        with open(f'target_page_{number}.html', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(target_html)
    driver.close()
    print('Finished')
```

Em seguida, chamei as duas funções fornecendo a URL inicial (https://www.diariodepernambuco.com.br/capa_busca.html?q=seguran%C3%A7a&q=seguran%C3%A7a%20%2B%20p%C3%BAblica%20%2B%20pernambuco&q=%22seguran%C3%A7a%20p%C3%BAblica%22%20%2B%20pernambuco&q=%22seguran%C3%A7a%20p%C3%BAblica%22%20%2B%20crime*%20%2B%20pernambuco).

**A excessão que foi retornada:**

```
 File "C:\Users\Victor\OneDrive\Scrapy Projects\Corpus_Jornais\teste_selenium_diariodepernambuco5.py", line 57, in <module>
    get_next_pages(url)

  File "C:\Users\Victor\OneDrive\Scrapy Projects\Corpus_Jornais\teste_selenium_diariodepernambuco5.py", line 40, in get_next_pages
    page.click()

  File "C:\Users\Victor\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

  File "C:\Users\Victor\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\Victor\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Victor\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

Entendo que através dessa excessão `StaleElementReferenceException`, é informado que o objeto desejado para o click() não está mais disponível, contudo creio que ele esteja na lista para ser acessado. Rodei o código da 2ª função em isolado, e depois pedi o tamanho da lista (`len(page_list)`), retornando a quantidade exata de referências que foram coletadas (=9).

Alguém teria alguma dica sobre como lidar com esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução pesquisando mais sobre o que estava acontecendo. Encontrei aqui no Stackoverflor em português uma resposta que me ajudou a estruturar o que eu precisava resolver. Para aqueles que se depararem com esse tipo de problema, segue:

Primeiramente, recomendo a leitura da resposta dada à essa questão: [Problemas de StaleElementReferenceException em Selenium com Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371493/problemas-de-staleelementreferenceexception-em-selenium-com-python)

Ela determina, em síntese, que se aquela exceção aparece é porque o elemento que o click() está tentando acessar foi perdido.

Construí a solução com base na ideia de que é preciso atualizar a lista a cada vez que seja feito um acesso à página na sequencia. A primeira função que criei foi mantida. A segunda ficou assim:

```
def get_next_pages(url): 
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    #Creating a list that receives all elements according to the given XPATH
    page_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page"]')
    pages_amount = len(page_list)
    #Creating a loop to update the pages list and get their target HTML
    for index in range(pages_amount):
        number = str(index+2)
        updated_pages_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-cursor-page"]')
        print(f'Accessing page {number}')
        updated_page_list[index].click()
        time.sleep(5)
        target_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="gsc-expansionArea"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        #Writing and saving a HTML file with the target code
        print(f'Saving page {number} html')
        with open(f'target_page_{number}.html', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(target_html)
    driver.close()
    print('Finished')
```

**Explicando o que eu alterei:**

No inicio da função ainda é criada uma lista de páginas (page_list), mas dessa vez, só como um referêncial para que possa ser calculado a quantidade de elementos nele (page_amount).

Com esse tamanho definido, pode-se realizar um 'for', onde em cada nova iteracão é criada uma nova lista de páginas (updated_page_list), acessando o elemento na posição indexada de acordo com a iteração.

Eu acrescentei alguns prints para ter uma visão daquilo que estava sendo feito, usando o number = str(index+2) para ter a referência ajustada das impressões em tela de acordo com a forma como a lista aparece originalmente no site (de 1 a 10, e não de 0 a 9).

Finalmente, os HTML alvos de cada uma das paginas listadas é raspado e salvo em arquivo numerado também de acordo com a variável "number".

Caso algum interessado tenha ficado com duvida em relação a essa resposta, é só falar aqui que terei o prazer de reiterá-la. E caso alguém tenha uma solução melhor, mais elegante, fica o espaço para apresentá-la.

Minhas saudações!